# What strategy should I use to store Social Network Sites user info to database with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I designed a database model like this. In this, I'd like to store user info from Facebook when they use Facebook or Google to login.

[image: Sns]

I use JPA with Hibernate to work with Database, so I need to map the database model to ORM.

**What I tried:**

I tried `MappedSuperclass` for `SnsProfile` abstract class but It doesn't work when I need to map SnsProfile with User entity.

I tried `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)` but if I have some more Social Sites and additional properties, the table is more and more complicated.

I would like to have some JPA Entity like this:

```java
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private UserStatus status;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade =  CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "user")
    private List<SnsProfile> profile;

}
```

```java
public abstract class SnsProfile implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String snsId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

```java
public abstract class FacebokProfile extends SnsProfile {
   // Properties here
}
```

```java
public abstract class GoogleProfile extends SnsProfile {
   // Properties here
}
```

Could you please give me some advice on Entity design to the database model above work well on JPA? Or any changes in Database model are welcome.

Please help. Thank you so much!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I updated my question. Could you please give me some advice on Entity design to the database model above work well on JPA? Or any changes in Database model are welcome.

Comment: "Work well"  is much too vague. Why don't you try implementing what you want and see if it fits your needs first?

Comment: Yes, I've tried but as I mention, if I have some more Social Sites and additional properties, the table is more and more complicated ( for strategy @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) )

Comment: You have to store them somewhere. But if you don't like the SINGLE_TABLE strategy, there are two other ones that you might prefer.

Comment: I tried MappedSuperclass for SnsProfile abstract class but It doesn't work when I need to map SnsProfile with User entity. So I'd like to some advices from experts like you :)

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance